# Age of Empires 3 "Initialization Failed"

Tags: technical-issues, age-of-empires-iii

So I found the CD set of Age of Empires 3 in a old box and decided to install it on my Windows 10 laptop. The install went fine nothing wrong there, but when I try to start up AoE it will show a screen that has `play`, `uninstall`, `website` and `exit` as the options. When I click on `play` it shows the loading screen and then an error pops up that says `Initialization Failed`. I tried enabling compatibility mode, but that didn't work so I'm here hoping someone else has had the same issue.

Just as a quick clarification, **This is not the Steam version (Age of Empires III: Collections), this is the regular CD version (Age of Empires III).**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Age of Empires 3 uses an old Windows feature called DirectPlay which is disabled by default in Windows 10. Here's how to turn it back on:

- Open your Control Panel
- Select Programs & Features
- Select Turn Windows features on or off
- Open the drop-down box labelled Legacy
- Check the box marked DirectPlay
- Save and exit

Hopefully you'll be able to install and play Age of Empires 3 now!

Comment: Appreciate it! That worked!